# Defining Function Pointers

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I am trying to call the internal Windows NT API function NtOpenProcess. I know calling internal APIs can be a bad idea, but for this particular tool I need the low-level access this API provides.

My problem is that to use such an internal API, I need to use Runtime Dynamic Linking, as specified in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686944(VS.85).aspx)

To do that, I need to define a function pointer to NtOpenProcess. Here's my declaration:

```
typedef NTSTATUS (NTAPI *_NtOpenProcess) (
OUT PHANDLE,
IN ACCESS_MASK,
IN POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES,
IN PCLIENT_ID OPTIONAL);

class procManager
{
    HINSTANCE hNTDLL;
public:
    procManager()
    {
        hNTDLL = LoadLibrary(L"ntdll.dll");
        if (!hNTDLL)
            throw std::runtime_error("NTDLL.DLL failure.");
        _NtOpenProcess NtOpenProcess;
        NtOpenProcess = reinterpret_cast <_NtOpenProcess> (GetProcAddress(hNTDLL, L"NtOpenProcess"));
        if (!NtOpenProcess)
            throw std::runtime_error("NtOpenProcess not found.");
        //Use NTOpenProcess for stuff here
    };
    ~procManager()
    {
        FreeLibrary(hNTDLL);
    };
};
```

Problem is, apparently there is an error in my typedef above. The compiler returns:

> error C2059: syntax error :
>   '__stdcall'

I used the handy dandy "Go To Definition" feature of my IDE (Visual Studio 2008) and found that NTAPI in the declaration is defined as __stdcall.

Unfortunately, removing NTAPI from my declaration, making it this:

```
typedef NTSTATUS (*_NtOpenProcess) (
OUT PHANDLE,
IN ACCESS_MASK,
IN POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES,
IN PCLIENT_ID OPTIONAL);
```

results in another error:

> error C2065: '_NtOpenProcess' :
>   undeclared identifier

At this point I'm saying "Of course it's undefined, that's why it's a typedef!"

Does anyone see my error in the declaration?

Comment: Get ntdll.lib from the DDK and link statically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you include "ntdef.h" and "ntstatus.h" ? 
The compiler probably cant understand NTSTATUS.

Comment: I thought I did lol... but here's the problem ->
#ifndef NTSTATUS
#define LONG NTSTATUS
#endif

I switched LONG and NTSTATUS around.

Thanks!